# Keep brand and toggler on same row when screen very small Bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap-4

Using Bootstrap 4, I have figured out how to make a generic navigation where the brand is on the left and links are on the right. I have also been able to make it collapse to a toggler when screen size goes below medium. My problem is that with a multi-word brand, when the screen becomes too small, the toggler goes below the brand. What I want is for the multi-word brand to collapse below itself and keep the toggler to it's right. Also, using "navbar-brand" prohibits a multi-word brand from collapsing at all. I had to just use "nav-link" instead for my brand to get it to collapse.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-light navbar-light border-bottom shadow-sm">
  <a class="nav-link" href="#"><font color="7c0000">THIS BRAND HAS A LOT OF WORDS IN IT</font></a>


  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>


  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">LINK</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">LINK</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">LINK</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">LINK</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">LINK</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">LINK</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>  
</nav>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This CSS properties can help...

- for normal screen sizes, we add our class to make sure that the long brand title can only occupy **75%** of the screen
- to further enhance it, we remove the padding when the size gets under **578px**
- to further improve it, we get the long brand title to occupy **50%** of the screen only

You can change these numbers to get the exact effect that you're aiming for...

```css
.nav-link {
  width: 75%;
}

@media screen and (max-width:478px) {
  .navbar {
    padding: 0
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:300px) {
  .nav-link {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-light navbar-light border-bottom shadow-sm">
  <a class="nav-link" href="#">
    <font color="7c0000">THIS BRAND HAS A LOT OF WORDS IN IT</font>
  </a>


  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>


  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">LINK</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">LINK</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">LINK</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">LINK</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">LINK</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">LINK</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: I added that script but it didn't change brand and toggler positions in the navbar

Comment: you mean that you added the style block? place the style block after the load of bootstrap.min.css... i.e. after `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">`

Comment: I copy and pasted your CSS between the <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"> and </script> and nothing changed. When I compare a page without your code to a page with in Safari's responsive design mode, both pages look the same on every screen size.